# Custom Context For Snippets Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-snippets

I would like to create a custom context for templates in eclipse.
How I can do it?

[image: http://i007.radikal.ru/1201/56/d1b1b03b7aae.png]

Answer (score 1):

It's an extension point provided by the platform, "org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates.  You can check the org.eclipse.jdt.ui plugin.xml for an example of how the existing contexts are defined.  If you want to show those templates during content assist, you'll also need to contribute an extension to org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer to actually use your context rather than the ones that JDT itself defines.  The JDT computer for templates only loads the templates from JDT's contexts.